# C++20: Validate Template Bodies Against Concepts

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts, definition-checking

C++20 introduces concepts, which allows us to specify in the *declaration* of a template that the template parameters must provide certain capabilities.  If a template is instantiated with a type that does not satisfy the constraints, compilation will fail at instantiation instead of while compiling the template's body and noticing an invalid expression after substitution.

This is great, but it begs the question: is there a way to have the compiler look at the template body, *before* instantiation (i.e. looking at it as a template and not a particular instantiation of a template), and check that all the expressions involving template parameters are guaranteed by the constraints to exist?

Example:

```
template<typename T>
concept Fooer = requires(T t)
{
  { t.foo() };
};

template<Fooer F>
void callFoo(F&& fooer)
{
  fooer.foo();
}
```

The concept prevents me from instantiating `callFoo` with a type that doesn't support the expression that's inside the template body.  However, if I change the function to this:

```
template<Fooer F>
void callFoo(F&& fooer)
{
  fooer.foo();
  fooer.bar();
}
```

This will fail if I instantiate `callFoo` with a type that defines `foo` (and therefore satisfies the constraints) but not `bar`.  In principal, the concept should enable the compiler to look at this template and reject it *before* instantiation because it includes the expression `fooer.bar()`, which is *not* guaranteed by the constraint to exist.

I assume there's probably backward compatibility issues with doing this, although if this validation is only done with parameters that are constrained (not just `typename`/`class`/etc. parameters), it should only affect new code.

This could be very useful because the resulting errors could be used to guide the design of constraints.  Write the template implementation, compile (with no instantiations yet), then on each error, add whatever requirement is needed to the constraint.  Or, in the opposite direction, when hitting an error, adjust the implementation to use only what the constraints provide.

Do any compilers support an option to enable this type of validation, or is there a plan to add this at any point?  Is it part of the specification for concepts to do this validation, now or in the future?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I statically check my templated class at definition time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335619/how-do-i-statically-check-my-templated-class-at-definition-time)

Comment: Why do you care whether the compiler error happens before or after instantiation?

Comment: @Spencer Because if it happens _before_ instantiation, the template author can fix the bug. If it happens _during_ instantiation, it's the user who gets the error on a template that might be an internal implementation detail of some library that they have no control over. It's _much_ better to get errors earlier (for the same reason that a compile error is better than a runtime error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: no.

The design for the original C++11 concepts included validation. But when that was abandoned, the new version was designed to be much more narrow in scope. The new design was originally built on `constexpr` boolean conditions. The eventual `requires` expression was added to make these boolean checks easier to write and to bring some sanity to relationships between concepts.

But the fundamentals of the design of C++20 concepts makes it basically impossible to do full validation. Even if a concept is built entirely out of atomic `requires` expressions, there isn't a way to really tell if an expression is being used exactly in the code the way it is in the `requires` expression.

For example, consider this concept:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
concept func_to_u = requires(T const t)
{
  {t.func()} -> std::convertible_to<U>;
};
```

Now, let's imagine the following template:

```
template<typename T, typename U> requires func_to_u<T, U>
void foo(T const &t)
{
  std::optional<U> u(std::in_place, t.func());
}
```

If you look at `std::optional`, you find that the `in_place_t` constructor doesn't take a `U`. So... is this a legitimate use of that concept? After all, the concept says that code guarded by this concept will call `func()` and will convert the result to a `U`. But this template does not do this.

It instead takes the return type, instantiates a template that is *not* guarded by `func_to_u`, and that template does whatever it wants. Now, it turns out that this template *does* perform a conversion operation to `U`.

So on the one hand, it's clear that our code does conform to the *intent* of `func_to_u`. But that is only because it happened to pass the result to some other function that conformed to the `func_to_u` concept. But that template had no idea it was subject to the limitations of `convertible_to<U>`.

So... how is the compiler supposed to detect whether this is OK? The trigger condition for failure would be somewhere in `optional`'s constructor. But that constructor is *not* subject to the concept; it's our outer code that is subject to the concept. So the compiler would basically have to unwind *every template* your code uses and apply the concept to it. Only it wouldn't even be applying the whole concept; it would just be applying the `convertible_to<U>` part.

The complexity of doing that *quickly* spirals out of control.

Comment: In the end, it's incumbent on the person designing function `foo` to analyze the  requirements imposed by the function body.   `requires func_to_u<T, U>` is there because of the use of `optional<U>`, not the other way around.

Comment: Thank you.  The concrete example of why definition checking is infeasible is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> Do any compilers support an option to enable this type of validation, or is there a plan to add this at any point? Is it part of the specification for concepts to do this validation, now or in the future?

No, no, and no.

The feature you're looking for is called *definition checking*. That is, the compiler checks the definition of the template at the point of its definition based on the provided concepts, and issues errors if anything doesn't validate. This is how, for instance, Rust Traits, Swift Protocols, and Haskell Typeclasses work.

But C++ concepts don't work like that, and it seems completely infeasible to ever add support for such a thing given that C++ concepts can be arbitrary expressions rather than function signatures (as they are in other languages).

The best you can do is thoroughly unit test your templates with aggressively exotic types that meet your requirements as minimally as possible (the term here is *archetype*) and hope for the best.

Comment: That sounds more like a job for a static analyzer -- It could generate an archetype based on concepts and requires clauses in the code and try to compile that.

Comment: @Spencer Well, that is what the compiler does - in the languages that support this feature. It's just that in C++ this basically infeasible. The issue here also isn't just _checking_ - it's coercing. If you have a `predicate<int> F`, I don't want to have to `(bool)f(42)` everywhere, since all I know is that this thing is convertible to `bool` and not that it is _is_ `bool` -- C++0x concepts did that for us too.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I accepted the other one because it gave a concrete example of the infeasibility.

As a developer who's already become deeply familiar with how different C++ templates are from generics in other languages like some you mentioned, but who's brand new to concepts, I'm now learning that concepts are also really quite different than generic constraints.